# Java logging dependency for a low-level library

Tags: java, dependencies

I inherited a lower-level open source Java network library.  The library is intended to be used by higher-level application protocol libraries which are in turn used by application code.  My library, as left by the previous maintainer, has no dependencies and is built via Ant.  The build artifact is a simple jar that others can drop into their projects.

I am in the process of converting the library to be built with Maven.  As I'm doing this, I'm considering *possibly* adding slf4j as a dependency.  Currently, when something goes wrong, stack traces or other information is spit out to System.out or System.err.  I know that that's not always very helpful, but these outputs only happen at 10 to 15 places in the code and are rarely executed.

So what do you think?  Keep the library simple with *zero* dependencies or introduce slf4j?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), you can include the slf4j jar (along with whichever implementation you prefer) **inside** your deployed jar. There are more complicated options if you want to allow users to choose the logging library, but it will run perfectly well if you [make a fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven) with or without the slf4j implementation.

Users are much more likely to be annoyed - unless hard drive space is really (and I mean really) at a premium - if they have to deal with `System.out` and `System.err` output than if there's a provided logging framework, even if it's just the default no-op implementation and the have to add log4j or logback if they want to see the logs.

Answer (score 5):

Coding to the SLF4J API doesn't force the dependency on users of your library. From the [user's guide](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#libraries):

> As of SLF4J version 1.6.0, if no binding is found on the class path, then slf4j-api will default to a no-operation implementation discarding all log requests.
>
> ...
>
> Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a library declares a transitive dependency on a specific binding, that binding is imposed on the end-user negating the purpose of SLF4J. Note that declaring a non-transitive dependency on a binding, for example for testing, does not affect the end-user.

Comment: I wouldn't be adding an implementation dependency, but the slf4j-api is a dependency on its own.  Users would need to add my jar plus the slf4j-api jar.

Answer (score 1):

I often prefer standard and good enough over best.  There could be a "less is more" argument for using the included Java Logging:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html

Comment: I would recommend against the direct use of the Java logging API. It has an unfortunate problem in that it contains a static collection that ends up holding a reference to every class that logs something. Because this is part of core Java and not an application framework, it's owned by the bootstrap classloader, and may end up with references to your applications classloader. In frameworks that use multiple classloaders to allow dynamic code reloading (eg Tomcat), this can lead to serious memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for the advice to be cautious of memory leaks related to Java logging API.  IMHO, this is a problem with the implementation, not the API.  I hope they will fix is some day.  Until then, I'll still be using the standard, albeit limited and somewhat broken, logging.  For production I always restart Tomcat when deploying a new version of software.  For development I have to restart Tomcat a couple times a day.